# Can I use jQuery or JS to rotate a canvas image around its center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, rotation

Simple question, I'm drawing an image on the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(img, 500, 500);` I want to rotate this image around its central axis an undetermined degrees measure (somewhere from 0-360). I know that there is a jQuery library called [jQuery rotate](http://jqueryrotate.com). However, I looked at the API of this, and it looks like it only can rotate HTML elements. I know I could rotate the entire canvas, but that is not really what I want because there are other things being drawn that I don't need rotated. Is there any way I can rotate just the one image using jQuery or javascript?

Comment: jQuery is only for DOM Elements, so no you can't. But with Javascript you can--view the link Downgoat posted.

Comment: @Jerry yeah I did, we were talking about it in PPCG chat, I think that it will work. Although, he suggested (since he is more up-to-date on my project and has seen it quite a bit) that I should change my objects to DOM elements and just work with those since its easier. IDK, will see.